# RETAG: cs.ds.data-structures to ds.data-structures-algorithms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

This is a proposal to

- retag cs.ds.data-structures as ds.data-structures-algorithms
- rename algorithms as a tag synonym of ds.data-structures-algorithms

Comments ?

as an aside, maybe this should be the template for future retagging requests.

**Update**: Two tag synonyms have been created: ds.data-structures $\leftarrow$ cs.ds.data-structures, and ds.algorithms $\leftarrow$ algorithms. Nothing has been merged YET, but that can also be done to rewrite history entirely.

Comment: Too long. Max 24 characters.

Comment: If we believe Wirth when he says that data structures + algorithms = programs, shouldn't we retag it ds.programs?

Comment: Is this proposal completed?  I do not see the [ds.data-structures-algorithms] tag yet.

Comment: Or is the proposal modified?  In that case, I appreciate if you append to the post what has been actually done.

Comment: apologies. I'll amend the post accordingly

Comment: @Suresh: Thanks!

Comment: It might be good to manually check questions with the old cs.ds.data-structures tag; some of those need to be retagged with ds.algorithms and some of them with ds.data-structures.

Comment: You could also create another synonym: ds.data-structures <- data-structures. I think these *can* be safely merged.

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer a split into two separate tags: ds.data-structures and ds.algorithms.  Some questions would be reasonably tagged with both, of course.

(Actually, I'd prefer the arxiv-free tags "algorithms" and "data-structures", but I've already lost that battle.)

Comment: Made the same suggestion on another thread.

Comment: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/118/proposal-remove-discipline-prefix-from-the-arxiv-style-tags/132#132 Anyway, I strongly support having two tags... "data-structures-algorithms" is way too coarse of a tag to have for a TCS website.

Comment: I have updated the proposal http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/118/proposal-remove-discipline-prefix-from-the-arxiv-style-tags/132#132 so that we have two DS tags.